# Linkedin Javascript API (Blank Page)

Tags: linkedin-api

I have setup and configured an application with Linkedin and have followed their instructions regarding setting up the Javascript API (http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api)

I added the following to the head tag of my page:

```
api_key: my-api-key
```

And the following to the body tag

```
Hello, <?js= firstName ?> <?js= lastName ?>.
```

I placed both as described in the Linkedin tutorial but all that results is a blank page with zero source content when I load the page.  Can anyone help me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the Script in such a way that it makes use of the LinkedIN APIs provided in https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-tutorial

I've written a working JS code where you can extract firstName,lastName,industry,summary,headline,specialties,positions,interests and educations hope this helps.

http://infinityexist.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/extracting-connection-details-using-linkedin-apis-written-in-javascript/

Regards